# Resque on Heroku Cedar not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, redis, resque

I've been trying to figure what the issue is for couple days now but no luck, I'm running Rails 3.1.3 on Heroku Cedar with Unicorn and using Resque 1.20 for background jobs.

Redis add-on as been added and REDISTOGO_URL set, I have resque.rb initializer as

```
require 'resque'
Resque.after_fork = Proc.new { ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection }

uri = URI.parse(ENV["REDISTOGO_URL"])
REDIS = Redis.new(:host => uri.host, :port => uri.port, :password => uri.password)
Resque.redis = REDIS
```

I also tried

```
Resque.redis = Redis.connect(:url => ENV['REDISTOGO_URL'])
```

Also this, from the official RedisToGo site

```
ENV["REDISTOGO_URL"] ||= "redis://username:password@host:1234/"

uri = URI.parse(ENV["REDISTOGO_URL"])
Resque.redis = Redis.new(:host => uri.host, :port => uri.port, :password => uri.password,     :thread_safe => true)
```

Heroku worker as:

```
bundle exec rake resque:work QUEUE='*'
```

Everything works fine locally and in Heroku console; but when I try to queue from Rails

```
Resque.enqueue(EmailQueue, id)
```

I get

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `sadd' for nil:NilClass):
```

Please any help will be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out, since I was on Unicorn; I had to set config/unicorn.rb as below to connect or Redis.

```
after_fork do |server, worker|
 # Replace with MongoDB or whatever
  if defined?(ActiveRecord::Base)
     ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
     Rails.logger.info('Connected to ActiveRecord')
  end

# If you are using Redis but not Resque, change this
 if defined?(Resque)
    Resque.redis = ENV['REDISTOGO_URL']
    Rails.logger.info('Connected to Redis')
 end
end
```

Hopes this helps someone else.